# 2021 Community Moderator Election - vote now!

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway! This is an election to add one new moderator - the existing three moderators are all continuing.

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase - if there are more than 10 nominees
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to vote for Ken Graham but can find no way of doing that. I can't click and drag apart from getting his name in to the deselect box! I can't click anywhere to actually vote for him! There are supposed to be more than the 4 nominations that appear, but I cannot get beyond that to find out who the other 6 are. I'm wasting a lot of time trying to vote and failing.

How do I actually vote for this one candidate I want to vote for?

2 Days Later - Success!  Thank you for that link to curiousdannii's answer to Nigel, Lesley. That worked. But I still don't know who the other 6 candidates are. If there are another 6, could someone tell me how to see a list of their nomination answers?

Comment: No, there were only 4 nominations. If there had been more than 10 nominations there would have been an extra primary stage to cut down the list to 10, but as there were only 4 we went straight to the election.

Answer (score 2):

Like Anne, I tried to vote for Ken Graham but I'm not sure if my vote has been counted.  He only has 6 x votes which surprises me.

I did not want to vote for any of the other candidates so have not attempted to click and drag their names anywhere.

How do we know if we have successfully cast a vote?

Comment: Can you tell me how you thought you'd voted? I know for sure I have been unable to vote, but you think you managed it.

Comment: Well, I thought a message popped up saying my vote had been counted (this was a couple of days ago) but since then, what appears on the screen in the box where I voted for Ken Graham remains static.  It would be a shame if votes are not being counted.

Comment: But how did you click a 'vote' link? Where is the link to actually vote?

Comment: On the right hand side of the Election Page (showing all the candidates and their comments) is a box which says: Your ballot.  I honestly can't remember what I did to select Ken Graham - I'm a bit of an I.T. dunce.

Comment: The page I went to is this one: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election

Comment: That's exactly the same one I went to, but got nowhere trying to find out who the other 6 nominees were, let alone how to vote for one of them!

Comment: Check out Curious Dannaii's answer to Nigel J's question: https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/how-do-i-vote-in-the-moderator-election/3839#3839

Comment: @Lesley There shouldn't be any indication on which candidate receives how many votes before the election is over.  How do you know that Ken has only 6 votes?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - Ah, my misunderstanding.  I saw the 6/40 score (and 5/40, 8/40 etc) by each candidate and thought that meant so-and-so had got 6 out of a total of 40 votes.  Just me being dense.....

Comment: @Lesley Ah... it makes sense now. :-)  Happy voting.