# How do I vote in the Moderator Election?

Tags: support

Despite attempting it, I am baffled as to how to do it.

(And, apparently, I am not the only one.)

Comment: Browser or mobile?

Comment: @curiousdannii Browser, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Screenshot of the ballot box]

On the right side of [the election page](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election/2) is the ballot box. Drag as many candidates as you wish to vote for into the top box. You can also rearrange them later if you want.

Comment: I've done that but there is no 'save' facility and when I navigate off the page I have no reassurance that my vote was counted.

Comment: @NigelJ Ah. Votes are automatically saved. You'll see a little note at the top of the ballot box saying "pending save", and then a few seconds later, "selections saved".

Comment: @NigelJ - best way to test if it's saved is to go back to the page and see if it's as you left it. I think the strength of the approach is that you have until the deadline to reorder if you change your mind for any reason, rather than a submit button like we used to have.

Comment: Thank you @curiousdannii

Comment: Thank you @SteveTaylor

Answer (score 2):

You are not alone! The last Christianity Stack Exchange Moderator Election was straightforward and uncomplicated.

This Biblical Hermeneutics Moderator Election has me baffled.  I think I cast one vote, but I'm not sure if it has been counted.

Given the very low number of votes that have been registered, I wonder if there is a fault in the system - perhaps this will be corrected during the scheduled maintenance that starts today.